# Define Python class member function with *args

Tags: python, parameters

In Python how could I define a member function with an unknown number of parameters without using keyword arguments?
Something like this:

```
class Foo:
    def speak(self, *args):
        ...
```

Comment: Looks like you've already got it. What's still confusing you?

Comment: inside your `speak` method, `args` is just a (potentially empty) Python list - just work with it/iterate over it as you normally would with  any other list.

Comment: Ohh, so it works. Actually I tried to `print("%s" % args)` but it always raises error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` so I thought Python doesn't support `func(a1, a2, *args)` like Ruby.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: btw, if I do like this:
`def speak(*args):
        for a in args: print(type(a))`

It seems that the first `a` is not recognized as a `Foo` class but `Int` instead.

Comment: You're running into a common pitfall with `%`-style string formatting. `args` is a tuple, so its *elements* are matched against placeholders in the format string. (You didn't need string formatting there anyway; `print(args)` would have done what you wanted.)

Comment: Regarding your second comment, that doesn't make any sense, and [I don't see anything like that](https://ideone.com/Sn3cyq) when I try it.

Comment: My bad, the first `a` is actual of `Foo` class. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do just that pretty easily. Note that you can iterate through each element in `args`.

```
class Foo:
    def speak(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            print(arg, end=" ")
            
bar = Foo()
bar.speak("Hello", "I", "am", "bar")
```

Output:

> Hello I am bar